# Proving that $U \ \backslash \ \left\{u\right\}$ is complete

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. How to prove that if a system of vectors $U$ is complete and some vector $u ∈ U$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors in $U \ \backslash \ \left\{u\right\}$, then the system of vectors $U \ \backslash \ \left\{u\right\}$ is also complete?

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this? Have you thought about the definition of completeness?

Comment: What does it mean for a system of vectors to be complete?  Do you mean complete in the topological sense?